# Customize product model in Spartacus to set new property in ngrx store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, spartacus-storefront

Currently we are extending Spartacus code and we need to be able to customize the model with some new properties.

The custom product-list-component component uses productListComponentService to set value of type ProductSearchPage model.

How to override the model to add new properties based on some change and store the value using ngrx, to store and fetch new state data with new properties in different components.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done just by extending the OOTB ProductSearchPage model in your custom models. Add your keys in that. (Use of? might be needed depending on your app). Import Your new ProductSearchPage from custom models into your ProductListCompoenentService.

That should do the trick.